# Stop using Sudo on AWS?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, sudo

I'm really new to AWS. I've just launched an Ubuntu 16.04 instance and I've noticed that I have to use sudo for practically everything. Is there a way to give an Ubuntu user permissions so I don't have to write `sudo` every time? I have to use `sudo` even to initialize a git repository.

Thanks

Comment: How about logging in as root?

Comment: @codeforester that's not an option on AWS

Comment: @MarkB, e login as root to all our ec2 instances.

Comment: @Roger, if you **have** to use `sudo` to `git init`, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Thank you all. I think that a solution could be to use :

Comment: Thank you all. I think that a solution could be to use :
    sudo chmod 770 <directory or file>
So you don't have to use sudo everytime

Answer (score 2):

Giving your user permissions to run everything without invoking `sudo` is just wrong. It's a bad security design. Although it's possible, I will not include this in my answer.

However, if you **absolutely sure** you want to execute a bunch of commands without using `sudo` on all of them you can run `sudo su -`. This will give you command line with `root` priviliges.